# Maximum call stack exceeded inside the function only when the parameter is passed

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I was trying to sort the characters of an array in the ascending order.
The following is the code which works fine.

```
let des = [4,8,6,3,5,10,56];
let final = [];
let format = des.length;
let now =0;

function element(){
    let today=des[now];
    for (var i=0; i<des.length; i++){
        if(des[i]<today){
            today = des[i];
        }
    }
    if(final.length!==format){
        final.push(today);
        des.splice(des.indexOf(today),1);
        element();
    }
}

element(); //[3,4,5,6,8,10,56]
```

---

but when I try to insert the code in to function  with the parameter like the following

```
function delement(desArray){
    let final = [];
    let now =0; 
    let today=desArray[now];
    for (var i=0; i<desArray.length; i++){
        if(desArray[i]<today){
            today = desArray[i];
        }
    }
    if(final.length!==4){
        final.push(today);
        desArray.splice(desArray.indexOf(today),1); 
        delement(desArray);
    }
    console.log(final);
}

delement(des); // maximum call stack was extended at desArray.splice(desArray.indexOf(today),1);
```

it was showing the error that maximum call stack was extended at desArray.splice(desArray.indexOf(today),1);

Please someone help. I can't understand why it was happening

Comment: `final.length` will **always** be `!==` to 4, because it's a local variable and a new `final` is created on every call to the function.

Comment: Adding to @Pointy, Please make sure to put a return statement on a condition basis to exit when you call the function recursively.

Comment: May I ask you whether you are intentionally avoiding to use `Array.prototype.sort()` ([see on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)), please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize variable `final` only once

```
function delement(desArray, final){
    let now =0; 
    let today=desArray[now];
    for (var i=0; i<desArray.length; i++){
        if(desArray[i]<today){
            today = desArray[i];
        }
    }
    if(final.length!==4){
    final.push(today);
    desArray.splice(desArray.indexOf(today),1); 
    delement(desArray, final);
    }
    console.log(final);
}
delement(des, []);
```

In the calling function the `final` object is set as an empty array and its initialized only once here

Comment: You could also use a default value so you don't need to pass an explicit `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your variable inside but arrange your recursion properly..
Ditch the format, your desArray will get to zero so use that, also use sort instead of making your own logic.

```js
let des = [4, 8, 6, 3, 5, 10, 56];

function delement(desArray) {
  let final = [];
  let now = 0;
  let today = desArray[now];
  for (var i = 0; i < desArray.length; i++) {
    if (desArray[i] < today) {
      today = desArray[i];
    }
  }
  if (desArray.length !== 0) {
    final.push(today);
    desArray.splice(desArray.indexOf(today), 1);
    final = [...final, ...delement(desArray)];
    return final;
  }
  return final;
}

console.log(delement(des))
```